# Is it safe to mix LED lamps with different wattages in the same fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led

I have a lighting fixture with 3 lamps. The current ones are LED on 6W.
One has burned out and I bought a replacement one at 35W.
Is it OK to have 2 at 6W and 1 at 35W or should all the lamps be the same?

Comment: Is this a LED light fixture with a single LED driver or just a light fixture you put LED lights(with own driver) in(upgrade from incandescent)?  If second then should work, but have two dim and one bright.

Comment: What is the maximum wattage listed on the fixture? Was it originally for LED or incandescent bulbs? It will look funny with one bulb being considerably brighter than the other two.

Comment: If stuff was simple, three 6W equals 18W of light.  35W would 2x as bright as 18W(plus an extra 12Ws).  Depending on how the 18W lighted up the room, then it might be too bright.

Comment: Is the fixture enclosed and if so is it a single enclosure for all three bulbs?

Comment: a 35w LED? That's crazy strong if that's right...

Comment: @crip659: "Is this a LED light fixture with a single LED driver or just a light fixture you put LED lights" I am not sure what the driver is but I suspect the second you mention. Is there something to check?

Comment: @FreeMan: The other 2 will need replacement soon, I thought to buy just one for now and was wondering if it is safe. Max wat is 100. "Was it originally for LED or incandescent bulbs?". I don't know to be honest. I bought it from IKEA. Is there something I can check?

Comment: @jay613: It has 3 separate places to put the bulbs. Does that mean it is enclosed?

Comment: @dandavis: ah sorry about that. It is 3.5W=35W=255lumen. So it is 35W equivalent

Comment: Enclosed means there is a glass globe or bowl that completely encloses the bulb, with the opening of the bowl held tight against the metal body of the lamp.  As opposed to being open on top, or completely open or having vents.

Comment: Oh if you want to mix a 3.5W LED with some 6W LEDs bulbs you can ignore my other questions.    A 35W (actual) LED would produce a lot of heat that could cause rapid failure of all three bulbs if the are together in an enclosed fixture.

Comment: You should edit our question for clarity, and not use actual and equivalent watts in different ways without clarification.

Comment: In my experience, one bright bulb in a multi-bulb fixture just won't light as well as dimmer bulbs in each socket. If, however, you're happy with it, there's no problem doing so as noted in Ecnerwal's answer. If it's just short term, that's not an issue, either, as you'll be balancing the lighting soon.

Comment: "will need replacement soon"... LEDs shouldn't need replacement on any kind of schedule, they should run nominally forever, but realistically until their internal power supplies fail, which is highly variable based on build quality.  200 hours, 50,000 hours, all comes down to quality of capacitor. However, if good ones are burning up regularly, they may be getting too hot because heat can't escape the fixture.

Answer (score 5):

So long as you don't exceed the maximum wattage listed for the fixture, it should be fine - but it will look strange, perhaps - that's aesthetics, not function, though.